# How come rake needs bundle exec, but rails doesn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I appreciate all the answers out there as to what bundle exec does, which is that it runs the following commands in the context of the Gemfile bundle. But why doesn't "rails server" need bundle exec? Seems like it should still apply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23846736/3307520 good explanation here

Answer (score 3):

The `rails` command runs from the executable inside the `script` folder. If you remove this folder, you can see that `rails` commands stop working. `rake` however runs differently.